# login through the session or cookies created in virtual server

Tags: session, cookies, session-hijacking

As we know when we login to a system, they creates some type of sessions or cookies to keep track which user is logged in and further processing is based on sessionid or cookies.

Is it possible to get the session or cookies from virtual server and access website from some other location or browsers?

For example :- I have login credentials of a website abc.com, I logged in that website on remote server and get the sessionid or cookies created by website on remote server browser.
Next based on that sessionid or cookies without login to abc.com again I can access the whole features? Is it possible or not? If yes then how?

may be some type of session hijacking?

Note: I don't need it for hacking purpose.:)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SE. I'm not completely sure what you require, here. But it almost sounds like you want a separate session which doesn't use your current cookies. If so, this can be achieved by using private browsing (available in most browsers), or opening a different browser. If that's not what you mean, you may need to explain a little more precisely what you want to do.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply, but I have multiple websites in my database and each website has login credentials. I don't want to show user login screen for each website. He need to login once and later which website he want to access will auto login from database credentials. To make it secure I want to login remote server and then pass session or cookies created at server. Hope that help to understand.

Comment: It looks like what you are suggesting can not be done, but there are a number of alternatives available. This question may provide you with a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies